# How to remove the title from a chart in TornadoFx

Tags: javafx, tornadofx

I have a scatterplot that I would like to fit into an existing view:

```
scatterchart("Test", NumberAxis(), NumberAxis()) {

}
```

[image]

But I would like to get rid of the title at the top to centre the scatterplot in its view.

I have tried to set the title to an empty string but to no avail:

```
scatterchart("", NumberAxis(), NumberAxis()) {
    // I'm looking for a method like this:
    title.isVisible(false)
}
```

[image]

My goal is to get rid of that empty space at the top of the chart for a uniform look.

I'm not even sure what the correct way would be in JavaFx. Let me know if I'm on the right track, cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Set the `title` to null:

```
scatterchart(null, NumberAxis(), NumberAxis())
```

Alternatively:

```
scatterchart(x = NumberAxis(), y = NumberAxis())
```